# How to assign individual values as payload to axios call?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an array with dynamic length. The array can be of length 5, 50 ,100 or anything.

The API requires payload as follows

```
axios.post("My_API_URL",{
result_ids1: myArray[0],
result_ids2: myArray[1],
result_ids3: myArray[2],...
})
```

How to pass this dynamic parameter to my `axios` call depending on the length of my array so I don't have to write each and every parameter manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using `reduce`

```js
const myArray = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 1010]

const payload = myArray.reduce(
  (acc, el, index) => ({ ...acc, [`result_ids${index + 1}`]: el }),
  {}
)

console.log(payload)
```